# Hybrid approach with OpenMP and MPI does not use same number of threads in cluster with different number of hosts

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

I'm testing a hybrid approach by paralleling the friendly-numbers (CAPBenchmark) program with MPI and OpenMP.

My cluster has 8 machines and each machine has a 4 core processor.

The code:

```
/*
 * Copyright(C) 2014 Pedro H. Penna <pedrohenriquepenna@gmail.com>
 * 
 * friendly-numbers.c - Friendly numbers kernel.
 */

#include <global.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util.h>
#include "fn.h"

/*
 * Computes the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers.
 */
static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  int c;

  /* Compute greatest common divisor. */
  while (a != 0)
  {
     c = a;
     a = b%a;
     b = c;
  }

  return (b);
}

/*
 * Some of divisors.
 */
static int sumdiv(int n)
{
    int sum;    /* Sum of divisors. */
    int factor; /* Working factor.  */

    sum = 1 + n;

    /* Compute sum of divisors. */
    for (factor = 2; factor < n; factor++)
    {
        /* Divisor found. */
        if ((n%factor) == 0)
            sum += factor;
    }

    return (sum);
}

/*
 * Computes friendly numbers.
 */
int friendly_numbers(int start, int end) 
{
    int n;        /* Divisor.                    */
    int *num;     /* Numerator.                  */
    int *den;     /* Denominator.                */
    int *totalnum;
    int *totalden;
    int rcv_friends;
    int range;    /* Range of numbers.           */
    int i, j;     /* Loop indexes.               */
    int nfriends; /* Number of friendly numbers. */
    int slice;

    range = end - start + 1;
    slice = range / nthreads;
    if (rank == 0) {

        num = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);
        den = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);
        totalnum = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);
        totalden = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);

    } else {

        num = smalloc(sizeof(int) * slice);
        den = smalloc(sizeof(int) * slice);
        totalnum = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);
        totalden = smalloc(sizeof(int)*range);
    }

    j = 0;
    omp_set_dynamic(0);    
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, n) default(shared) 
    for (i = start + rank * slice; i < start + (rank + 1) * slice; i++) { 
            j = i - (start + rank * slice);
            num[j] = sumdiv(i);
            den[j] = i;

            n = gcd(num[j], den[j]);
            num[j] /= n;
            den[j] /= n;
    }
    if (rank != 0) {
        MPI_Send(num, slice, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(den, slice, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i < nthreads; i++)  {
            MPI_Recv(num + (i * (slice)), slice, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);
            MPI_Recv(den + (i * (slice)), slice, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (i = 1; i < nthreads; i++) {
            MPI_Send(num, range, MPI_INT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(den, range, MPI_INT, i, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    } else {
        MPI_Recv(totalnum, range, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,0);
        MPI_Recv(totalden, range, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD,0);
    }

    /* Check friendly numbers. */
    nfriends = 0;
    if (rank == 0) {
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        omp_set_num_threads(4);
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) default(shared) reduction(+:nfriends)
        for (i = rank; i < range; i += nthreads) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                /* Friends. */
                if ((num[i] == num[j]) && (den[i] == den[j])) 
                    nfriends++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        omp_set_num_threads(4);
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) default(shared) reduction(+:nfriends)
        for (i = rank; i < range; i += nthreads) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                /* Friends. */
                if ((totalnum[i] == totalnum[j]) && (totalden[i] == totalden[j])) 
                    nfriends++;
            }
        }

    }
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (i = 1; i < nthreads; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&rcv_friends, 1, MPI_INT, i, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);
            nfriends += rcv_friends;
        }
    } else {
        MPI_Send(&nfriends, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    free(num);
    free(den);

    return (nfriends);
}
```

During the executions I observed the following behavior:

When I run `mpirun` with 4 and 8 hosts, each of the hosts uses 4 threads for processing, as expected.

However when running using only 2 hosts only 1 thread is used on each machine.
What could cause this behavior? Is there any alternative to "force" the use of the 4 threads in the case of the 2 hosts?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Open MPI.

The default binding policy is to bind to socket or numa domain (depending on your version). I assume your nodes are single socket, which means one MPI tasks is bound to 4 cores, and then the OpenMP runtime will likely start 4 OpenMP threads.

A special case is when you start only 2 MPI tasks. In this case, the binding policy is to bind to core, which means one MPI task in only bound to one core, and hence the OpenMP runtime only start one OpenMP thread.

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you can

```
mpirun --bind-to numa -np 2 ...
```

If it fails, you can fallback to

```
mpirun --bind-to socket -np 2 ...
```

Comment: bind-to numa did not work. So I tried bind-to socket and it worked. Thank you @Gilles Gouaillardet

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I edited my answer accordingly. IIRC, `hwloc < 2` does not detect a single socket node as a single numa domain node, and hence the error. Future Open MPI versions will be based on hwloc 2, and that should fix the issue.

Comment: In the second command, the first dash in `—-bind-to socket` is a long dash instead of a normal dash, so copy-pasting the command will fail. It should be `--bind-to socket`. The suggested edit queue is full, so I can't propose this change.